# How to quit beeline?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am using CDH 5.5 and need to use beeline. I am pretty new to it and learning it now. I can start beeline but cannot quit as we do in Hive. I need to use Ctrl+z to quit which is not the proper way. Can someone help?

Comment: Ahem - on Unix/Linux `CTRL-Z` means *STOP*, it does not terminate the program, it "freezes" it and returns control to the shell... without closing the connections nor de-allocating RAM & temp files.

Comment: For the record, the usual way to close a command-line utility in interactive mode is `CTRL-D` which means *OK, no more input, Stdin channel is closed, you can exit now*

Answer (score 37):

use `!q` or `!quit`

> [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ beeline
>
> Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.5.0 by Apache Hive
>
> beeline> !q
>
> [cloudera@quickstart ~]$

Thanks to Xuefu Zhang. Related [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4557)

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes you may find yourself with some unterminated command that Hive still thinks that you are entering.  If your "! quit" command isn't working, throw in a terminate character (;) and try to quit again.

---Example---

```
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.7.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> some unterminated command
beeline> ! quit
beeline> <panic!>
beeline> <remember the need to terminate previous commands>
beeline> ;
No current connection
beeline> ! quit
```

Comment: This was such a lifesaver, I actually went into <panic> when the command didn't work for the first time :)

Answer (score 7):

I tried !q and also !quit it did not work in HDP 2.5./Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.

Finally

> ! quit 
>   or ! q (space required)

Answer (score 4):

Using Clouder 5.5.1,

used Ctrl+C to exit

Comment: That's not the proper way to terminate an application.

Answer (score 2):

Quitting beeline client:

```
!quit
```

Answer (score 0):

beeline>!quit

This really helpful to quit the beeline